# Error: Get config: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library in Prisma and nextjs

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, supabase, supabase-database

I use nextjs fresh project with Prisma and supabase database. I'm using ubuntu.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

when I run Prisma push and generate command in my project. I face the same error with npm and yarn.
I run all Prisma command. I start with a fresh supabase database.

```
prisma migrate dev
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Error: Get config: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library

Prisma CLI Version : 3.15.2
```

```
 npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Error: Get config: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library

Prisma CLI Version : 3.15.2
```

`prisma/schema.prisma` file

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
}
```

After I added the environment variable.

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:EeVVG-password-wDiII@db.qpzh-url-opda.supabase.co:5432/postgres"

I do not find why I'm facing errors with Prisma and supabase. I'm deleting the `node_modules` folder and creating one more project. but the problem is not solved.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Check if you're in a sandbox terminal. In my case, my anaconda environment was on and so, I couldn't initiate the migration. Open a fresh terminal without any environments or sandboxes. Also, Looking into other solutions, I found out that if your nodejs installation is done using `snap`, then also this error occurs. Try reinstalling nodejs using `apt`.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same error.

Downgrading `node` from **18** to **16** solves this problem for me. I did't find better solution for this problem. Reference: [prisma github comment](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13478#issuecomment-1148063354).  *I don't recommend to downgrade though.*

But prisma works normally on `node 16 lts`.